# How to link to local files with variable names in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a local folder with images of playing cards (1 image per 1 card) with a certain naming pattern:

```
2_of_clubs.png
2_of_diamond.png
2_of_hearts.png
2_of_spades.png
3_of_clubs.png
...
```

As the folder with images is located in the folder with the program (html, css, and js files), I can refer to one specific file (say, Jack of clubs) with "/Cards images/jack_of_clubs2.png".

However, as I use a random card generator, I need to link to the files (display images) based on the results of the function (therefore, the **name** of the file that needs to be displayed in a specific moment is a **variable** returned by the function). The code of the function is as follows:

```
//Returns a random card as an object with ranking and suit as attributes
function Random_Card_Generator(){
    card_rankings = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
    card_suits = ["spades", "clubs", "hearts", "dimond"]
    Random_Card = {ranking: card_rankings[Math.floor(Math.random()*13)], suit: card_suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)]}
    return Random_Card
}
```

How could I open the image which file name will be the result of this function? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you need to declare your variables, e.g. with `const`, unless you've defined them previously. Once you have the variables you can use a template literal to get the filename. So I propose to do the following:

```
function Random_Card_Generator(){
    const card_rankings = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"];
    const card_suits = ["spades", "clubs", "hearts", "diamond"];
    const randomRank = card_rankings[Math.floor(Math.random()*13)];
    const randomSuit = card_suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
    const randomCard = `${randomRank}_of_${randomSuit}.png`;  //you can change this so that it fits the format of how your pictures are saved
    return randomCard;
}
```

Then you need to find the image in your html and change its source attribute:

```
const img = document.querySelector('img'); //or give it an id and use that with #
img.src=Random_Card_Generator();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare your arrays every time the function is called.

You can declare them once and use them in all the other functions.

Also, you can set the `.src` attribute of the `<img/>` tag to set the name of the file you want to display.

See my sample code below.

```js
const card_rankings = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"];
const card_suits = ["spades", "clubs", "hearts", "diamond"];
const cardPlacement = document.getElementById('cardChosen');
const imagePlacement = document.getElementById('cardImg');

//Returns a random card as an object with ranking and suit as attributes
function randomCardGenerator() {
  let randomCard = {
    ranking: card_rankings[Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)],
    suit: card_suits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]
  }
  return randomCard;
}


function chooseNewCard() {
  let cardChosen = randomCardGenerator();
  let imageFilename = cardChosen.ranking + '_of_' + cardChosen.suit + '.png';

  cardPlacement.innerHTML = cardChosen.ranking + ' of ' + cardChosen.suit;
  console.log(imageFilename);
  imagePlacement.src = imageFilename;
}
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="chooseNewCard()">Generate Card</button>
<img id="cardImg" src="" height="100" width="60" />
<div id="cardChosen"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your Random_Card_Generator function would return a object containing indexes of card_rankings, card_suits. First of all, you need to have access to both arrays outside the functional scope if you want to do card name creation outside of this function but I will do it inside this function for my convenience.

```
function Random_Card_Generator(){
   card_rankings = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
   card_suits = ["spades", "clubs", "hearts", "dimond"]
   Random_Card = {ranking: card_rankings[Math.floor(Math.random()*13)], suit: card_suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)]}
    
   const selectedCardFileName = `${card_rankings[Random_Card.ranking]}_of_${card_suits[Random_Card.suit]}.png`;
    
   return selectedCardFileName
        }
```